# Stopping fullpage.js SetInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I have used fullpage.js on my website's homepage, and I have made it so that it scrolls automatically every 10 seconds.
I have used the function as it is below:

```
$( '#fullpage' ).fullpage({
    continuousVertical: true,
    loopHorizontal: false,
    resize: false,
    afterRender: function() { // so that it applies to first section too
        forceScroll();
    }
});
slideTimeout = setInterval( function() {
    $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
}, 10000);
function forceScroll() {
    var slideTimeout;
}
```

However, I'd like to use `clearInterval(slideTimeout)` when the user slides down or sideways using his mouse, as when I want to browse afterwards it keeps going up and down... which is really annoying.
But I can't seem to find the trigger for it, or any workaround really!
How am I able to make this work?

[Documentation for Fullpage.js on GitHub](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js);
[The website I am speaking about](http://www.notsotypicaldesign.com)

Thank you a lot in advance,
Filipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand true, you want to unbind your interval when user scrolls.

```
$('body').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
        if (typeof slideTimeout !== "undefined") {
            clearInterval(slideTimeout); //case for scroll up
            alert("Timeout clear");
        }
    } else {
        if (typeof slideTimeout !== "undefined") {
            clearInterval(slideTimeout); //case for scroll down
            alert("Timeout clear");
        }
    }
});
```

Here is an example version of the system

```js
    var slideInterval = setInterval(function() {
        $("#counter").text(parseInt($("#counter").text()) + 1);
    }, 1000);

    $('body').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
           clearInterval(slideInterval);
           alert("Timeout clear");
        } else {
           clearInterval(slideInterval);
           alert("Timeout clear");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter" style="height:6000px;">0</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have used your example with the Mousewheel browser cross-over (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel)!
Is there a way to make is so that it doesn't trigger when the "timer" is already cleared/stopped?

Answer (score 0):

fullpage.js doesn't provide any callback for mouse wheel /trackpad events I'm afraid.

You would have to do it by yourself as @Ahmet Can Güven indicates. But I would recommend you to look for a more cross browser solution `mousewheel` won't work in all browsers.

Comment: Thank you, I have used Ahmet's example with the Mousewheel browser cross-over (github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel), thanks for the browser support heads up!